# Why Is This File Copied to the Root of a Docker Image Instead of the Working Directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-copy

Using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ["somefile", "/"]
```

and the `build` following command:

```sh
docker build \
--file=Dockerfile \
--no-cache=true \
--progress=plain \
--tag=someimage:sometag \
.

=>

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
. . .
#8 naming to docker.io/someimage:sometag done
#8 DONE 0.0s
```

why is `somefile` found at the root (`/`):

```sh
docker run someimage:sometag ls -altr ../../../.

#=>

total 68
. . .
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           128 Jul 27 12:34 somefile
. . .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 27 12:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 27 12:34 .
```

and not the working directory (`/usr/src/app`):

```sh
docker run someimage:sometag ls -altr .

#=>

total 8
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Jul 27 12:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jul 27 12:34 .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COPY` instruction in your `Dockerfile`:

```
. . .
COPY ["somefile", "/"]
. . .
```

uses an *absolute* path instead of a *relative* path; more on that [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

Replacing `/` with `./` will `COPY` `somefile` to `/usr/src/app` instead of the root dir:

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ["somefile", "./"]
```

We can locate `somefile` after we `build` the image with:

```sh
docker run someimage:anothertag ls -altr .

#=>

total 16
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           128 Jul 27 23:45 somefile
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 27 23:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 27 23:45 .
```